# How to sync 2 Elements (2 different pages) via Pusher

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, websocket, pusher

Is it possible to sync the innerHTML of 2 divs (or any other HTML element or ASP.net control) via Pusher?

My 1st page has an div that I use to insert iframes to PDFs/other files via jquery. I am trying to find a way to also push that data to a div on another page, so that clients can see what files are being displayed.

Please excuse me if this is a naive question - I am new to Javascript and Websocket.

I am building my site via ASP.NET MVC4, if that makes a difference.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea to send the actual HTML code over Pusher as that can turn out to be quite a lot of data. Have you considered sending the URL for the iframes to each connected client so they can synchronise and load up the same page?

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to do!  Do you have any suggestions on how to begin to achieve this?  I'm currently looking into SignalR. But, again, still trying to wrap my head around how these technologies work.